# Django template tags forloop

Tags: python, django

I have created a template tag and trying to loop through the results from the template tag
but I don't get any results

tags.py

```
from django import template
from loadprograms import dbcontext

register = template.Library()


    @register.simple_tag
    def get_category():
        x = dbcontext.DBContext()
        results = x.executequery("Select name from Categories")
        categories = [each[0] for each in results]
        return categories
```

template code

```
{% load category_tags %}
{% get_category %}
{% for each in get_category %}
    {{ each }}
{% endfor %}
```

The {% get_category %} prints all the categories without any issues but the for loop stmt
that loop through the results does not work

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is this your actual tag?

Comment: Yes..Thats the actual tag.

Comment: Why you are using raw SQL?? Why not use ORM ?

Answer (score 3):

To make this change in your tag, you'll have to [set a variable in the context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context), but if your objective is to have a list of categories available in templates, just like you would have passed it in from the view - then you need to write a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), which will allow all views to have this variable in their context.

A template context processor is just a method that adds to the request context, by returning a dictionary.  Think of it like a view function, that just returns a context.

```
from .models import Categories

def cat_names(request):
    return {'category_names': Category.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)}
```

To activate this context processor, you have to do a few things:

1. Add the above code to a file called `template_processors.py` in the same place as your `models.py` and `views.py`.
2. In your `settings.py`, add the fully-qualified name of the *method* to the [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) setting, making sure you don't override the defaults. To do this easily, import the default settings first, then add to it:

   ```
   from django.conf.default_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + ('yourapp.template_processors.cat_names',)
   ```
3. Use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render), which will make sure the context is correctly passed.

In your views, you can now just do this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
   return render(request, 'home.html')
```

In your `home.html`, you can now do:

```
{% for name in category_names %}
   {{ name }}
{% endfor %}
```